# Como ler arquivos CSV usando python e plotar gráficos

Tags: python, csv, gráfico

Gostaria de saber como faço para chamar dois arquivos em csv, ler e plotar um gráfico com as medias dos dois arquivos csv.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Sua pergunta tem problemas, ela não é um exemplo [mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Sem as melhorias necessárias ela não resulta em uma pergunta útil para a comunidade. Sugiro ler o [Guia de Sobrevivência do SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá. Maria,
você pode usar a biblioteca csv
Para usá-la use import csv

```
import csv

#Aqui você vai abrir seu arquivos
csv1 = open("pasta_do_arquivo\nome.csv", "r")
csv2 = open("pasta_do_arquivo\nome2.csv", "r)

#Para ler os arquivos csv
leitor_csv1 = csv.reader(csv1, delimiter="")#nao esqueça de colocar qual o tipo de delimitador entre cada célula se é , ; :
leitor_csv2 = csv.reader(csv2, delimiter="")

#para obter cada linha use um for
for linha in leitor_csv1:
    print(linha)#se tiver mais de um dado em uma linha, ele retorna uma lista
```

Se quiser saber mais, acesso documentação
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Para plotar gráficos você pode usar matplotlib
para instalar

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Na documentação do matplotlib tem uma série de tutoriais que como fazer cada tipo de gráfico
[Documentação MatplotLib](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/tutorials/index.html)

Comment: Certo e caso eu queira plotar o gráfico da média, variância? Como eu faço para transformar os valores dos arquivos csv em numpy e depois plotar o gráfico?